# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array

Tags: powershell, csv

This is my .CSV file:
[image]

I use the following code to read the data from .CSV. Data read from the table will be converted into normal variable so that I can do some calculations.

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$TransportOptions = $ScriptPath + "\TransportOptions.csv"

$TransportOptionsID = @()
$TransportOptions = @()
$TransportEnergy = @()
$CO2 = @()

Import-Csv $TransportOptions |`
ForEach-Object {
    $TransportOptionsID += $_."TransportOptionsID"
    $TransportOptions += $_.TransportOptions
    $TransportEnergy += $_.TransportEnergy
    $CO2 += $_.CO2
}

$InputID = Read-Host -Prompt "TransportOptionsID"

if ($TransportOptionsID -contains $InputID)
{
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($TransportOptionsID, $InputID)
    $InputName = $TransportOptions[$Where] 

    if ($TransportOptions -contains $InputName)
    {
        $Where = [array]::IndexOf($TransportOptions, $InputName)
        $InputEnergy = $TransportEnergy[$Where] 
        $HTransportEnergy = [double]$InputEnergy

        if ($TransportEnergy -contains $InputEnergy)
        {
            $Where = [array]::IndexOf($TransportEnergy, $InputEnergy)
            $CO2transport = [double]$CO2[$Where]
        }
    }
}
```

But What I got is error:

```
ERROR: Import-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it  is an empty array.
ERROR:
CO2estimatorUserInputs.ps1 (132, 11): ERROR: At Line: 132 char: 11
ERROR: + Import-Csv <<<<  $TransportOptions |`
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
ERROR:
```

Do I miss something in my code? Any idea to solve this error, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you missed something:

```
$TransportOptions = $ScriptPath + "\TransportOptions.csv"

$TransportOptions = @() # This

Import-Csv $TransportOptions |`
```

You assigned the variable the CSV path, then reassigned it as an empty array before trying to pass it to `Import-Csv`.